# Create multiple charts using ASP.NET based only on the code behind

Tags: asp.net

I want to use ASP.NET charts created only in code behind. The reason is that I want to have different charts bind dynamically as many as my database have records. Anybody please help...
Here is my code:

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
String webname = "series1";
Chart1.Series.Add(webname);
Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("test", 5);
Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("test", 2);
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
```